# Some of my Apps suddenly gone, including ubuntu default apps

Tags: apt

So, I want to install Canon Ip1800 printer driver and looking for help in google, I found an article that said I need to type in terminal:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inameiname/stable
```

And then install synaptic package manager from software, after I did those, suddenly some of my apps are gone, including Ubuntu Default apps.

I don't know why, can you help me?

Comment: When you install something, it gives you a list of which all packages are going to be installed and which are to be removed. You should always check that before installing anything. You can check which packages were removed in `/var/log/dpkg.log` and manually install them. **Also, which package did you install from the PPA, and what is your version of Ubuntu?**

Comment: The [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~inameiname/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+packages) does not host packages for any recent version of Ubuntu (the latest supported version in the PPA is 16.04). Your issue may be due to something else.

Comment: Hey Yosi! Is this the article from which you followed instructions: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/558795/canon-printer-driver-scangear-mp-for-ubuntu-1404/?

Comment: Hello thank you for answering, yes, i followed that instruction, and currently i have ubuntu 21.04, Now i can't do anything other than open terminal and open some apps, even files app are gone, and sorry, I'm not sure what pkg i installed from the PPA, It's just all gone while I'm using the computer